# Infinity at event horizon boundary

Tags: black-holes, time, time-dilation, event-horizon

It has been repeatedly explained to me that from the perspective of an outside observer a particle takes "infinite time" to cross the event horizon of a black hole. Also, according to these explanations there is no information inside the black hole because nothing gets inside. Then I read answers to the contrary. Whether or not a particle can cross a horizon does not seem to be answerable when an "infinity" is used to describe events in time. I am not trying to make any statements by this question. I am asking for knowledge that is not conflicting because I also see many questions on this website (with answers) that deal with particles hitting a singularity, inner horizons and how an observer would feel when crossing the horizon for different size black holes (for examples) I hope no-one minds me splitting this question into two parts because I need to do so...

1) Does space-time curvature actually reach infinite curvature at the event horizon boundary?

and therefore...

2) Does anything cross the event horizon?

Comment: This has been answered numerous times and some of the answers have no-doubt confused you.  Try reading John Rennie's answer to the following question & I'll bet you'll then understand it. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/21356/167500

Comment: @D.Halsey - thank you sir